# Find longest substring of N unique characters

Tags: algorithm

Input:   str="abcdeefuiuiwiwwaaaa"  n=3
output:  "iwiwwaaaa"   (longest substr with 3 diff chars)

I have a solution as below. My questions:

1. How is the time complexity? 
   I know it must be better than O(n^2), but not sure whether can conclude it's O(n).
2. The solution below can not cover the whole ASCII, can we improve this without additional space?

   ```
   public static String getSubstrOfMChars(String str, int m) 
   {
        if (str==null || str.length()==0)
            return "";     

        int len = str.length();        
        String max = "";

        for(int i=0; i<len;) 
        {  
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int counter = 1;
            int checker = 0;
            char firstChar = str.charAt(i);
            int firstCharPos = i;    // first char position in the string
            sb.append(firstChar);
            checker |= 1 << (firstChar - 'a');

            for(int j=i+1; j<len; j++) 
            {  
                char currChar = str.charAt(j);
                if (currChar == firstChar) 
                    firstCharPos++;                

                int tester = checker & (1<<(currChar - 'a'));
                if ( tester > 0 ) // already have such character
                {
                    sb.append(currChar);
                    continue;
                }

                // new character
                if (++counter > m) 
                {
                   i = firstCharPos + 1;

                   if (sb.length() > max.length()) 
                   {
                       max = sb.toString();
                   }
                   break;
                }
                sb.append(currChar);                   
                checker |= 1 << (currChar - 'a');              
           }

           if (counter <= m) 
           {               
               if ((counter==m) && sb.length() > max.length()) 
               {
                   max = sb.toString();
               }               
               break;
           }

        }

        return max;        
   }
   ```

Comment: Your algorithm can accomodate a maximum of 32 values to check against since you are using `ints`. And I would double check the statement `I know it must be better than O(n^2)...`. To help, check out the summation of `1+2+3...+N`.

Comment: hint: think about how the value of j changes as you iterate through the first for loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an O(n). Let `S` be the string.
Just go through the array with two pointers `i` and `j` and keep track of number `K` of different letters between `S[i]` and `S[j]`. Increment `j` whenever this number is smaller or equal `n` and increment `i` whenever `K` is greater than `n`. Also remember the longest substring for which `K` was equal to `n`.

In the implementation you also need a hash table to keep track of the last occurrence of the letter.

Python implementation:

```
def longest(S,n):
    i = j = K = 0
    res = (0,0)
    last = {}

    while i < len(S):
        # if current substring is better than others than save
        if K == n and j - i > res[1] - res[0]:
            res = (i,j)

        # if we reach the end of the string, we're done.
        if j + 1 > len(S):
            break
        # if we can go further with the right end than do it
        elif K <= n and j + 1 <= len(S):
            if not last.has_key(S[j]):
                K = K + 1
            last[S[j]] = j
            j = j + 1
        # if we must go further with the left end than do it
        else:
            if last.has_key(S[i]):
                del last[S[i]]
                K = K - 1
            i = i + 1
    return S[res[0]:res[1]]
```

Comment: I think you need to check K == n rather than K <= n when assigning res=(i,j).

Comment: Sure, thanks! I forgot that we need exactly `n` characters. Fortunately it's just one character to change ;)

Comment: There is an off by 1 error. Current code didn't push character at index 0. You need to change the condition to `j+1 <= len(S)` and swap `j = j + 1` to after `last[S[j]] = j`

Comment: Thanks for remarks! I modified the code. Later I will also try to check it by myself.

Comment: Good solution! I like how you delete the entries from last[].

Comment: `if last[S[i]] == i: del last[S[i]]` , I doubt whether this could get correct result.

Comment: Why? Actually, after nhahtdh comments, it is not pseudo-code anymore and you can just run it and test it.

Comment: I actually implemented in java but for some reason it is not working different outputs. can you help out here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751753/code-to-find-longest-substring-with-unique-k-characters-not-working-for-all-inpu

Comment: There is a bug. If you do: `print longest("aabbcdeeeeggi", 3)`, the output is `bcdeeee`, which is incorrect. To fix it, you could do like this: `if last.has_key(S[i]):  key = S[i];  K = K - 1;   del last[S[i]];  while S[i] == key:  i = i + 1`

Comment: Since the value of last is never read (only the key is tested for inclusion), it could be a set. In any case 'K' will be decremented when a particular character is seen at 'i' but there could be more instances of that character between i and j.

Answer (score 2):

Your present code complexity is O(N^2) since you are using nested for loops to check for substrings that start from each character.

IMO you can do this in O(N*k) time and O(k) extra space (where k = number of unique characters allowed):

1. Iterate the string from the beginning and add the 1st character in a map of value to last position found.
2. Keep parsing the string and updating the last position found of each character in the map.
3. When you get a new character, increment the count of characters and make last position found for this character = current position.
4. When the count in map reaches k, iterate the `map` and search for the value of minimum position index. calculate `present position - min(last position index)` and update max length substring accordingly. Decrement count. Pop out this character from the map.
5. Continue the above till you reach the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are too complex. I'll throw an easy solution..

The problem's constriant revolves around the DISTINCT CHARACTERS.

-So, Our solution should  give priority to the UNIQUE character count  (unicount) at any time.

-There are two cases to consider. One is either the unicount < K  or  unicount >=K.

```
CASE 1: (unicount<K)
    1a: Str[i] is a new character not present already in the current window.
         --Increase unicount and hash[str[i]]
    1b: Str[i] is a not  new character present already in the current window.
        --No need to  increase unicount. Just hash str[i].

CASE 2: (unicount>=K)
    2a.  Str[i] is a not  new character present already in the current window.
        --No need to do anything cause unicount will be equal to K. Just hash str[i].
    2b. Slide the window (VARIABLE start) till the unicount value decreases..
         --Now similar to case 1.
```

Below code prints the Longest length of such substring with only K distinct characters. Its easy to modify this to actually print the such substring.

```
int printLengthKUniqueSubstring(string str,int k)
{
    int hash[256] = {0};

    int n = str.length();
    int unicount = 0,maxlength = 0,start = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(unicount<k)
        {
            if(hash[str[i]]==0)
            {
                hash[str[i]]++;
                unicount++;
            }
            else
                hash[str[i]]++;
        }
        else
        {
           // cout<<"hello "<<" "<<unicount<<" "<<i<<endl;
            if(hash[str[i]]>0)
                hash[str[i]]++;
            else
            {
                while(unicount>=k)
                {
                    hash[str[start]]--;
                    if(hash[str[start]]==0)
                        unicount--;
                    start++;
                }
                if(hash[str[i]]==0)
                {
                    hash[str[i]]++;
                    unicount++;
                }
                else
                    hash[str[i]]++;
            }

        }
        maxlength = max(maxlength,i-start+1);
    }
    if(unicount<k)
        return -1;
    return maxlength;
}
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Complexity `O(n*C)` where C is a constant for checking Key for the min Value of the Dictionary.

**Here is the solution in C#.**

```
public static string GetLongestSubString(string s, int numberOfUniqueChar)
{
    char c;
    int start = 0;
    string result = string.Empty, temp = string.Empty;
    Dictionary<Char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!dic.ContainsKey(s[i]))
        {
            dic.Add(s[i], i);
            if (dic.Count > numberOfUniqueChar)
            {
                temp = s.Substring(start, (i - start));
                if (temp.Length > result.Length)
                {
                    result = temp;
                }
                c = dic.OrderBy(k => k.Value).FirstOrDefault().Key;
                start = dic[c]+1;
                dic.Remove(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // increase index of the current key
            dic[s[i]] = i;

            //if last char not change then check current substring with the result
            if(i==s.Length-1){
                temp = s.Substring(start);
                if (temp.Length > result.Length)
                {
                    result = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is my approach to solve this question. First of all, it splits the string into groups of same chars; Then loops to retrieve all valid substrings; finally returns all possible longest substrings:

```
import re
def longest(S,n):
    # 1. groupby unique characters
    grp_S =  [ s[0] for s in re.findall(r'(([a-z])\2*)', S)]
    # 2. retrieve all valid combinations in tuples (characters count, substring)
    options = []
    for i in xrange(len(grp_S)):
        g = 0
        while i  + n  + g <= len(grp_S):
            if  (len(set( [x[0] for x in grp_S [i: i + n + g]])) == n and i  + n  + g  + 1 > len(grp_S)) or \
                (len(set( [x[0] for x in grp_S [i: i + n + g]])) == n and len(set( [x[0] for x in grp_S [i: i + n + g + 1]])) > n):
                options.append( (len(''.join(grp_S [i: i + n + g])), ''.join(grp_S [i: i + n + g])) )
                break
            else: g = g + 1
    # 3. return the list of all longest substrings
    return [ v[1] for v in options if v[0] == max(options)[0] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]
Simple with no error checking in short python syntax

Comment: You could've simply posted the code instead of a screenshot. And looking at your reputation, I think you should be knowing that by now.

Comment: i did this to discourage some one(a novice)  to copy paste code with no error checks with out writing, testing himself  as it happened with a person i was interviewing!  please give me one reason why you need copy/paste code? Are you a student?

Comment: thought screen shot looks pretty and shows up in google image search also with benefit of  fully automated posting right from my IDE with just one click and most importantly makes me practice the code before uploading. but for refined code with explanations, i would do as you say,  Please give good reason before down voting so i understand to help you out

Comment: Being able to copy and paste is the precisely the reason I'd avoid posting screenshots, as that allows someone to quickly test and make optimizations to your implementation. I understand you concern that students might copy and paste, but not everyone on SO is a student and most developers are looking for a quick initial solution (if not the best). And that aside, I think an answer should also accompany some explanation as it won't come up higher in search results with just a single line. If not explanations, the code should contain some comments (which will be good for the students also :)).