# code to find longest substring with unique K characters not working for all inputs

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Given a String, ""aabbcdeeeeggi" and k=3, the code should find longest substring with maximum of k unique characters. For the above input, it should be "deeeeggi".

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119224/find-longest-substring-of-n-unique-characters) is an elegant O(n) solution for the problem in Python. I am implementing in Java. but I am not getting the desired output for all the inputs.

```
public class SubStringWithKUniqueCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(longestSubStringWithUniqueK("aabbcdeeeeggi", 3));
        System.out.println(longestSubStringWithUniqueK("aabbcdeeeeggi", 2));
    }

    public static String longestSubStringWithUniqueK(String input, int k){
        int len = input.length();
        Set<Character> unique = new HashSet<>();

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int maxStartIndex = 0;
        int maxEndIndex  = 0;
        int maxLen = 0;
        char[] inputArr = input.toCharArray();

        while (i<len){

            if (count==k && j -i > maxLen){
                maxStartIndex = i;
                maxEndIndex = j;
                maxLen = maxEndIndex - maxStartIndex;
            }
             if (count<k && j<len){
                if (unique.add(inputArr[j])){
                    count++;
                }
                j++;
            }
            else {
                if (unique.remove(inputArr[i])){
                    count--;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
         return input.substring(maxStartIndex,maxEndIndex);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
eeeeggi //correct output
eeeggi //incorrect output
```

I am not able to capture where the bug is. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The first one looks right `k =` **3** `egi`...or it could be `deeeegg`. Both are correct.

Comment: The second should be `eeeegg` right?

Comment: yes, I updated above

Comment: You probably wanted to advance `i` in a loop as long as `inputArr[i]` doesn't change (btw, this will only get you closer, your algorithm isn't correct)

Comment: I tried the python solution in the link with the same input. The output is: `bcdeeee` and `eeeegg`. Did you notice? 'bcdeeee` is incorrect. So the python solution is not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation does not work the way as expected, is because the original python solution has bug. I made some modifications to your code. Hope it's now all right:

```
public class SubStringWithKUniqueCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(longestSubStringWithUniqueK("aabbcdeeeeggi", 3));
        System.out.println(longestSubStringWithUniqueK("aabbcdeeeeggi", 2));
    }

    public static String longestSubStringWithUniqueK(String input, int k){
        int len = input.length();
        Set<Character> unique = new HashSet<>();

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int maxStartIndex = 0;
        int maxEndIndex  = 0;
        int maxLen = 0;
        char[] inputArr = input.toCharArray();

        while (i<len){

            if (count==k && j -i > maxLen){
                maxStartIndex = i;
                maxEndIndex = j;
                maxLen = maxEndIndex - maxStartIndex;
            }
            // 1. if we reach the end of the string, we're done.
            if (j + 1 > len){
                break;
            }
            // 2. changed to count <= k here
            else if (count<= k && j<len){
                if (unique.add(inputArr[j])){
                    count++;
                }
                j++;
            }
            else {                          
                if (unique.remove(inputArr[i])){
                    // 3. remove all consecutive chars of the same value
                    char c = inputArr[i];  // save as temp char
                    while (inputArr[i] == c)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    count--;                          
                }                
            }
        }
         return input.substring(maxStartIndex,maxEndIndex);
    }
}
```

The output now is:

```
deeeegg
eeeegg
```

Comment: great answer!. isn't time complexity o(n^2)?

Comment: Yes, it is. Hope I can come up with a better solution;)

Comment: Added my solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119224/find-longest-substring-of-n-unique-characters/36796198#36796198)  in python, not so elegant though :-)