# finding the longest substring with k different/unique characters using hash c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hashtable

I came to the problem of finding the longest substring with k unique characters. For instance, given the following `str=abcbbbddcc`, the results should be:

- `k=2 => bcbbb`
- `k=3 => bcbbbddcc`

I created a function for this purposes using a hash table. The hash-table is going to act as a search-window. Whenever there are more than k unique characters inside of the current window, I shrink it by moving the current "start" of the windows to the right. Otherwise, I just expand the size of the window. Unfortunately, it seems to be a bug on my code and still I'm not able to find it. Could anyone please help me to find the issue? The output of my function are the start index of the substring together with its length, i.e. `substring(start, start+maxSize);`. I found some related posts [java-sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751753/code-to-find-longest-substring-with-unique-k-characters-not-working-for-all-inpu) and [python-sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119224/find-longest-substring-of-n-unique-characters), but still no C++ based solution using a hash-table.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::vector<int> vector;
typedef std::string string;
typedef std::unordered_map<char, int> unordered_map;
typedef unordered_map::iterator map_iter;

vector longestSubstring(const string & str, int k){

    if(str.length() == 0 || k < 0){
        return {0};
    }

    int size = str.length();
    int start = 0;
    unordered_map map;
    int maxSize = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char c;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        c = str[i];

        if(map.find(c)!=map.end()){
            map[c]++;
        }
        else{
            map.insert({c, 1});
        }

        while(map.size()>k){
            c = str[start];
            count = map[c];
            if(count>1){
                map[c]--;
            } 
            else{
                map.erase(c);
            }
            start++;
        }

        maxSize = std::max(maxSize, i-start+1);
    }

    return {start, maxSize};
}
```

Comment: Please don't create type-aliases of common types, especially if you name the alias just the same as a standard C++ container template. People reading your code could be very confused by the type `unordered_map` or `vector`. If you want to use type-aliases then use names that reflect the usage of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `maxSize = std::max(maxSize, i-start+1);` you must ensure that map size is exactly `k` - you can never reach `k` but current code instanly updates `maxSize` .

Also remember `start` value in own `max` code

```
    if (map.size() == k) 
        if (i - start + 1 > maxSize) {
            maxSize = i - start + 1;
            astart = start;
        }
...
return {astart, maxSize};
```

[Ideone check](https://ideone.com/ASfmju)

Comment: MBo, thanks a lot for the explanation and taking time to review my code. Almost everything became clear to me. Just one question, why do we need the new variable `astart`?

Comment: @Tin Because you can shift `start++;` inside while-loop and loose the best start position

Comment: do you say any other problem in the code? I tried the modification with the following input parameters `string str = "aabacbebebe"; int k = 3;`, and the result was `aabacb`, instead of `cbebebe`

Comment: ?? My check shows maxsize=7, start=4  (I replaced mentioned string with code from my answer)

Comment: MBo, do you mind in putting then the whole code/solution?

Comment: I added link to ideone

Comment: Mbo, thank you. I found the problem. I was doing in a newer version of my code `map.insert({c, map[c]++})`, instead of `map[c]++;` Since the `key` already existed, the "update/insert" was not being conducted.